# Custom IDA Decompilation Format

Tags: ida, decompilation, c, ida-plugin

Is there a way to customize the format of IDA's decompiled code?

e.g.

```
char buf[7]; // [rsp+5h] [rbp-1Fh]
```

to

```
char buf[ 7 ]; // [ rsp + 5h ] [ rbp - 1Fh ]
```

or

```
switch (c)
```

to

```
switch( c )
```

Comment: if you want it in the gui i dont know  but if you can export the decompilation to a file  using [batch](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/batch.shtml)  you can use say notepad++ and searchreplace '\(' with '\( '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible, either through a configuration option or through a plugin. For example, here is the part of the code that prints the `[rbp-1Fh]` from your example:

```
qsnprintf(v16, v36 - v16, "[%s%c%ah]", gpPlatformStackPointerName, v20, v29);
```

I.e. the format string that produces it is hard-coded in the binary and cannot be modified.

Comment: Unfortunate, but thank you for your answer with reference!